# Stepper to sequence back and forth

Tags: microcontroller, stepper-motor

I am new to Stepper Motors, I am a mechanical Eng. Have a slight disadvantage with the electronic end. I need a stepper to run one direction, then reverse in sequence. Will a Stepper programmer do this operation //

Comment: Yes it will.  You typically use a stepper motor driver to do this and program your GPIO pins for a certain sequence to make it turn one way and then the other.

Comment: Can I ask if you've considered a different motor technology other than stepper, such as a brushed DC motor? It may well result in a simpler and easier system. Really am asking from the dark :-)

Answer (score 1):

It definitely will work. But to not waste your time and money (engineering time is expensive) you should use stepper driver. Not just an IC, which is natural for electronics engineer, but a complete system. If it will work out and you will have to reduce costs or for whatever reason to design your own- very well, but don't let this activity to hold your own mechanical job. For stepper drivers google trinamic. They have probably all you may ever need.

Answer (score 0):

Many stepper controllers have two logic inputs for control (as well as DC supply voltage to run the stepper motor coils). One is **direction**, with clock-wise being one logic state, while counter-clockwise is the other logic state. The other input is **step**, where a change from one state to the other (and then back) rotates one step.
Some smarter controllers also have logic inputs to change the stepping sequence, allowing half-steps, or even micro-steps (fractions of a step). For instance, a stepper advertised as "1.8 degrees-per-step" can be convinced to half-step so that one **step** pulse advances by 0.9 degrees by such a controller.
[image: A generic stepper controller chip]
Note that "Ground" must be common to both the stepper DC power supply, and also to the computer that supplies logic signal inputs. For this example chip, "Vcc" would be the logic supply voltage (probably +5v). Stepper DC coil voltage is not shown in this case.

Comment: Could you please list this example part number?  It may help the OP, and I've been looking for a drop-in replacement for my stepper driver (UCN5804).

Comment: @calcium3000 Product recommendations discouraged here. Found the photo on: http://microcontroller123.blogspot.ca/2010/10/stepper-motor-controller_07.html